# Trait for enums convertible to isize

Tags: rust

I have several enums. Each of them has numeric tags and can be converted to integer (`isize`). I have a trait that all of them define. But instances of that trait are not convertible to integer any more, because the compiler can't prove all implementations are actually parameterless enums.

Is there any trait that would mean a type is a parameterless enum or that it is convertible to integer (by any means) that I could use as constraint in the generics that need to get the numeric value?

---

To be more specific, here is a code-sample ([also on play](http://is.gd/BHHR8u)):

```
enum Foo {
    a = 1,
    b = 2,
    c = 3,
}

enum Bar {
    d = 4,
    e = 5,
    f = 6,
}

trait Process : std::marker::MarkerTrait {
    fn process(v: isize) -> String;
}

impl Process for Foo {
    fn process(v: isize) -> String { format!("foo{}", v) }
}

impl Process for Bar {
    fn process(v: isize) -> String { format!("bar{}", v) }
}

// just for sake of argument; something more complex in reality, of course
fn extern_call(v: isize) -> isize { 2 * v + 211 }

fn process<T: Process>(v: T) -> String {
    T::process(extern_call(v as isize))
}

fn main() {
    println!("a: {}", process(Foo::a));
}
```

Obviously the problem is in `process`, `v as isize` fails to compile with

> error: non-scalar cast: `T` as `isize`

So I would like to do something like

```
process<T: Process + scalar>
```

or

```
process<T: Process + ToPrimitive>
```

or something that would tell the compiler that only types that can be cast to isize are permitted, but I don't know what that could be.

Answer (score 0):

Add a method to your trait that coerces it to a `isize`. Then the compiler can verify that the objects meet the required criteria:

```
enum Foo {
    A = 1,
    B = 2,
    C = 3,
}

enum Bar {
    D = 4,
    E = 5,
    F = 6,
}

trait Process: {
    fn as_isize(self) -> isize;
    fn process(v: isize) -> String;
}

impl Process for Foo {
    fn as_isize(self) -> isize { self as isize }
    fn process(v: isize) -> String { format!("foo{}", v) }
}

impl Process for Bar {
    fn as_isize(self) -> isize { self as isize }
    fn process(v: isize) -> String { format!("bar{}", v) }
}

// just for sake of argument; something more complex in reality, of course
fn extern_call(v: isize) -> isize { 2 * v + 211 }

fn process<T: Process>(v: T) -> String {
    T::process(extern_call(v.as_isize()))
}

fn main() {
    println!("a: {}", process(Foo::A));
}
```

FYI, `MarkerTrait` isn't needed here (and is un-idiomatic):

> MarkerTrait is intended to be used as the supertrait for traits that don't have any methods

Comment: That's the obvious solution, of course. It's also not exactly nice when there is 15 or so of those enums.